# mysql: what is the best way to index multicolum in this scenario

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following sql command which takes lot of time. I am thinking of indexing

```
SELECT `daily_price_history`.`high`,
       `daily_price_history`.`low`,
       `daily_price_history`.`open`,
       `daily_price_history`.`datetime`,
       `daily_price_history`.`close`,
       `daily_price_history`.`creation_time`
FROM `daily_price_history`
WHERE (`daily_price_history`.`datetime_utc` BETWEEN '2015-12-04 18:43:28.710229' AND '2020-12-02 18:43:28.710229'
       AND `daily_price_history`.`symbol` = 'A')
ORDER BY `daily_price_history`.`creation_time` ASC
```

So indexing multiple columns `(datetime_utc,symbol)` is the best way or index two separate columns.

My `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

```
CREATE TABLE `daily_price_history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `symbol` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `symbolExpectionCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `url` longtext NOT NULL,
  `volume` double NOT NULL,
  `high` double NOT NULL,
  `low` double NOT NULL,
  `open` double NOT NULL,
  `datetime` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `datetime_utc` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `close` double NOT NULL,
  `creation_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `lot_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `periodType` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `symbolId_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `daily_price_history_symbolId_id_30077f62_fk_symbol_list_id` (`symbolId_id`),
  KEY `datetime` (`datetime`),
  CONSTRAINT `daily_price_history_symbolId_id_30077f62_fk_symbol_list_id` FOREIGN KEY (`symbolId_id`) REFERENCES `symbol_list` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11549349 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I have a table called `symbol_list`, so here `symbol` is just text of symbol, whereas `symbolId_id` is a foreign key relation to the `symbol_list`

Comment: I would just index on date time and try out. The type of index should be btree or any other type of index that allows selecting ranges.

Comment: what about symbol

Comment: In my opinion, you will not get much by including symbol: once the rows within date time range have been selected, further filtering can quickly be done in memory. You can try both options.

Comment: @Tarik - This scenario is an excellent example of where `INDEX(symbol, dt)` will significantly out perform `INDEX(dt)` or `INDEX(symbol)` or `INDEX(dt, symbol)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL will use just one index per table reference in most cases. So creating two separate indexes is not the best strategy.

You would be better off with an index on `(symbol, datetime_utc)`. The order of columns in the index is important!

Your query has an equality condition for `symbol` so it should go first.

The range condition for `datetime_utc` makes it better to put that second.

You can't optimize for both a range condition and the ORDER BY. You have to pick one or the other to optimize.

So the index should be one of:

- `(symbol, datetime_utc)` - optimizes for both search terms, but this will require a filesort of the result.
- `(symbol, creation_time)` - optimizes for the ORDER BY, avoiding the filesort, but won't optimize for the datetime_utc condition.

Which one is better? It depends on your data, and how many rows match your conditions. There's no simple answer, you'll just have to test both.

You might like to view my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or [the video of me presenting it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Comment: We see `WHERE (daily_price_history.datetime_utc BETWEEN '2015-12-04 18:43:28.710229' AND '2020-12-02 18:43:28.710229' AND daily_price_history.symbol = 'A')`. So the order is `datetime_utc` and then `symbol`. So will not mysql ignore the index `(symbol, datetime_utc)` which you are mentioning

Comment: `Your query has an equality condition for symbol so it should go first.` I am not aware of this, so could be the reason

Comment: No, MySQL's optimizer is designed to know that `AND` is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). In other words, `A AND B` gives the same result as `B AND A`. So regardless of the order you write the terms in your query, MySQL can use the appropriate index.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `PRIMARY KEY`.  It needs to be unique.  If you can guarantee that `(symbol, datetime_utc)` will always be unique, then this is optimal:

```
PRIMARY KEY (symbol, datetime_utc)
```

If you cannot guarantee uniqueness, then do

```
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (symbol, datetime_utc, id),
INDEX(id)
```

(Change `INT` to `BIGINT` if you might eventually have more than 4 Billion rows.)

This is puzzling:

```
WHERE    datetime_utc ...
ORDER BY creation_time
```

It would be faster and usually give the same results (maybe even *better* results) to us the same column for both:

```
WHERE    datetime_utc ...
ORDER BY datetime_utc
```

If you expect to have billions of rows, you should shrink each datatype as much as practical.

- Do you also have a `volume` column?  Some of the indexes won't fit in an `INT`.
- Normalize `symbol` and replace it with, perhaps, `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes, up to 64K values) or something similar.
- Values for `open`, etc won't fit in some smaller datatypes for BRK.A.
- Penny stocks may need more than 2 decimal places.
- Old readings were in fractions, with the denominator being a power of 2.
- Caveat: The above advice is based on US markets; other markets may have more issues.

The name `daily_price_history` implies one row per symbol per day?  Yet the use of an 8-byte `DATETIME(6)` implies you are recording every trade.  (`DATE` is only 3 bytes.)

After making some changes, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the main queries, and answers to my questions.  I may have more advice.

Comment: I am using TD america data. I have duplicates. Because some times by mistake i  may get the data twice, So i use `creation_time` along with the datetime. So for a symbol there can be multiple with same datetime. I will take the recent stored using `creation_time`. Also the data will grow eventually.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi - Change the `INSERT` to `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` so that it will automatically "update" when there is a dup.  Maybe then you can get rid of `creation_time`.

Comment: But, i have to get 10,000 symbols data daily and if using `INSERT` with update, it takes lot of time. currently i am using batch insert so it takes 2.5hrs. As td america does not allow more than 2 request per sec, eventhough they say 120 requests per sec

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi - I don't understand the issue.  It is the data collection that takes the time, not the `INSERT` or IODKU statement.  A batch `INSERT` of 1000 rows will take only a few seconds.  But it takes 500 seconds to get those 1000 'rows' from td amarica.  Or is a "request" more than one symbol?

Comment: And, you can "batch" with IODKU.

Comment: I think the OP meant to create a single index based on two columns: date and symbol, not multiple indices.

Comment: @Tarik - Yes to a composite index.  `symbol` must be first for performance.  But then I presented a case where multiple indexes would be even better.